# Can no longer access shared Eclipse project after moving Git repository folder in file system

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have created a project in Eclipse (Mars) and placed it under Git version control. I noticed that Eclipse [moved](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/241172/) the project in the file system as part of this sharing. As an effect, the project's files no longer resides inside the Eclipse workspace directory but inside a Git repository folder (defaults to `~/git/`) instead.

Afterwards (and from outside Eclipse), I have also renamed the repository folder. This now has the (obvious) effect that Eclipse can now longer access project because one or more "pointers" have become invalid.

It looks as I might be able to adjust this "pointer" by editing the Eclipse project's path variable `PROJECT_LOC` inside Eclipse (under `Preferences`). However, it is apparently read-only.

So how can I fix this problem, i.e. tell Eclipse that a project that it (or EGit on its behalf) chose to place outside the Eclipse workspace directory has moved to yet another place in the file system?

Answer (score 0):

The following sequence of steps (all inside Eclipse) apparently solves the issue:

1. delete project
2. `File` | `Import` | `Existing Projects into workspace`; `Select root directory:` path consisting of final location of repository folder plus project name (e.g. `/Users/me/git/myproject/`); `Copy projects into workspace`: off